# white screen with textureRegion with some images

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm  trying to "port" my game from badlogicgame engine to libgdx and I have a strange problem.
I've seen some posts like this that's happening to me, but i think that's this is a little different (that's the reason I opened another post, but if you think that this was answered in a previous one I'll close it).

Well I start, I'm using superJumper font

package com.redgehog;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class MainMenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    IceBucketMulti game;
    OrthographicCamera guiCam;
    Rectangle soundBounds;
    Rectangle playBounds;
    Rectangle highscoresBounds;
    Rectangle helpBounds;
    Vector3 touchPoint;

    public MainMenuScreen (IceBucketMulti game) {
        this.game = game;

        guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(480, 320);
        guiCam.position.set(480 / 2, 320 / 2, 0);
        soundBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64);
        playBounds = new Rectangle(160 - 150, 200 + 18, 300, 36);
        highscoresBounds = new Rectangle(160 - 150, 200 - 18, 300, 36);
        helpBounds = new Rectangle(160 - 150, 200 - 18 - 36, 300, 36);
        touchPoint = new Vector3();
    }
    public void draw () {
        GL20 gl = Gdx.gl;
        gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        guiCam.update();
        game.batcher.setProjectionMatrix(guiCam.combined);

        game.batcher.disableBlending();
        game.batcher.begin();
        game.batcher.draw(Assets.backgroundRegionSU, 0, 0, 480, 320);
        game.batcher.end();

        game.batcher.enableBlending();
        game.batcher.begin();
        game.batcher.draw(Assets.mainMenuRegion,  10,  200 - 110 / 2, 300, 110);
        game.batcher.end(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void render (float delta) {
        update();
        draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause () {
        Settings.save();
    }
}
```

It works with the original background, but when I put my image it stops working... I don't understand the reason... I tried to change the size and ppp to match the original image but the same result.

I tried to put the entire texture and then it works... I tried this code with the original libgdx superjumper version and with the last libgdx version.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have any output from the console? maybe something like "java.io.IOException: Error loading pixmap: 8bit only"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

The problem was inside "Assets file", I didn't change [new Texture("background.png")] for [loadTexture("background.png")]

sorry and thanks